# how to find the sum of the salaries in every dep in every year?

Tags: mysql, sql

i need to find the the sum of the salary spent in every year in every department - the problem is that i have two columns of date - how can i "extract" the year from this dates?
[image]

Comment: the only two relevant tables is: "dept_emp" and "salaries"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you're likely looking for is using the `YEAR` function to get the start date of the salary and summing up per department.

This is making the assumption that you want to count the full salary based on the year in which the pay started. Additionally, there may be added complexities if for example, someone worked for multiple departments at once. If you are asking which out of from or to date should be used to count which year the salary falls in, this is 100% up to you based on your requirements.

```
SELECT 
    a.dept_no as `Department`,
    YEAR(b.From_date) as `Year`, 
    SUM(b.salary) as `Salary`
FROM 
    dept_emp a
INNER JOIN
    salaries b
ON 
    a.emp_no = b.emp_no
GROUP BY
    a.dept_no,
    YEAR(b.From_date)
ORDER BY 
    a.dept_no
```